# How to sniff a USB port under Windows?

Tags: windows, usb, sniffing, usbserial

From time to time, I need to dump USB traffic under Windows, mostly to support hardware under Linux, so my primary goal is to produce dump files for protocol analysis.

For USB traffic, it seems that [SniffUsb](https://web.archive.org/web/20151218000528/http://www.pcausa.com/Utilities/UsbSnoop/default.htm) is the clear winner... It works under Windows XP (but *not* later) and has a much nicer GUI than earlier versions. It produces *huge* dump files, but everything is there.

However, my device is in fact a USB serial device, so I turned to [Portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx) which can sniff serial port traffic without the USB overhead.

Comment: Was this a question then?

Comment: I imagine it was once a question, but that the user answered it himself, and edited that answer into the question instead of filing it as an answer. (Boo!)

Comment: Portmon is Windows 3.2 or so, and doesn't support 64-bit.  SniffUSB is not supported on Windows Vista or 7.

Comment: @Mike: Perhaps Procmon would be of use in such cases?

Comment: I wound up using VMWare's USB logger and [Virtual USB Analyzer](http://labs.vmware.com/flings/virtualusb) since I had Windows in a virtual machine already.

Comment: You can use [USBPcap](http://desowin.org/usbpcap/) and Wireshark.

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/usb-reverse-engineering-down-the-rabbit-hole-c4809a5b55c4

Comment: @GEOCHET My Q was: How do I sniff USB serial on Windows? 
But you are right. Origin was an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I'd use [QEMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU) or [KVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine) and instrument their USB passthrough code, and then use [libusb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libusb) to prototype the replacement driver in user space (this latter bit I've done before; [writing USB device drivers in Python](http://pyusb.berlios.de/) is fun!).

Comment: Under Linux you'd use Wireshark, no ned to profile code or anything so complicated. However read to the end of the question.

Comment: When did Wireshark sniff usb? We're not talking about Ethernet here.

I know the questioner is asking about USB serial, but since the topic asks about USB sniffing in general, folks who find this question will expect an answer suitable to the overall topic.

Comment: Thnaks, as a next step I will probably try to run it under qemu or kvm.

Comment: Wireshark 1.10.0rc1 and above support USBPcap (detects existing install, or allows installing it). See high rated non-accepted answer by jamkomo, and followup comment stating that Wireshark can now do that on Windows. You may have to uninstall existing version--see https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/48789/usbpcap-tutorial

Comment: Many years later, I am interested how to use `QEMU` or `Docker` maybe for this, could you give me any place to start?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin, you can't use Docker for this -- it has to be qemu. Docker isn't virtualization or emulation, just a bunch of namespaces; it doesn't give you any hooks to sniff hardware's behavior you wouldn't have just running the software directly on the host.

Answer (score 19):

After five years waiting, now it's possible to sniff usb packets on windows

See http://desowin.org/usbpcap/tour.html for a quick tour. It works pretty well

Answer (score 14):

1. Since people don't seem to realize it, [Wireshark](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB#Windows) does monitor USB traffic and has a parser for it; but the catch is it only works under Linux. Wireshark on Windows will not do this.
2. It may be possible to plug the USB device you want to monitor, along with a Linux machine (with Wireshark running) and your Windows machine and just use the USB device under Windows.
3. Problem with the above? I don't know how the Linux machine or the Windows machine will detect each other.

Comment: USB uses a star topology with a single host per bus, I don't know how you expect to connect a linux box to a bus hosted by Windows, and even if you did, it wouldn't see traffic going to other devices (unless the linux box was a hub).

Comment: Wireshark can now sniff USB data on Windows machines too.

Answer (score 7):

Busdog, an open source project [hosted on github](https://github.com/djpnewton/busdog), has worked well for me.  It has a driver it installs to allow it to monitor USB communications.  The config window allows you to reinstall or remove the device at any time.

You can select the USB device you want from an enumerated list.  A nice feature is to have it automatically trace a new device that is plugged in:

[image: Enumerated USB devices]

Data communications to and from an SWR analyzer I was reverse engineering were captured flawlessly:

[image: USB-to-serial port communications captured]

Comment: In a quick test, BusDog unfortunately prevented an application from accessing the USB device, so there was no traffic for BusDog to sniff.

Answer (score 6):

[USBSnoop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/usbsnoop/) works too - and is free.

Or, you could buy a **USB to Ethernet** converter and use whatever network sniffer you prefer to see the data.

Comment: If you look at URL of SniffUsb, it includes USBSnoop because it's based on it :-)

Comment: A network sniffer and a usb-ethernet converter is only going to sniff ethernet. Because it's not converting the raw usb, it won't let you see the individual usb packets which is what a tool like usbsnoop will provide.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Message Analyzer was able to capture USB traffic, with `Device and Log File` parser from MS: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/capture-and-view-ing-usb-traces-with-microsoft-message-analyzer-)

Update: as mentioned by @facetus, MS Message Analyzer [has been retired on November 25 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/blog/ms-winintbloglp/dd98b93c-0a75-4eb0-b92e-e760c502394f).

Comment: It's been retired on November 25 2019, no replacement is available from Microsoft. Microsoft has removed all download links. An error message appears if you start already installed MMA after November 25 2019.